# Default MySQL value to be result of a query

Tags: mysql, auto-update

Is it possible for a column's default value to be the result of query whereby the value will automatically update whenever the value is queried?

I have a db with a members and a cancellations table and i would like the members.NumberOfCancellations value to be populated automatically to be the result of the pseudo query below:

select all from cancellations that has a cancellations.date less than 31 days from today where cancellations.memberid is equal to $phpvariable

i know this can be done with php and select/update scripts but i was hoping phpmyadmin may have had this feature?

```
______________________________________________________________
|memberid  |   firstname  | lastname  | numberofcancellations|
______________________________________________________________
|1         |   john       | doe       | resultofquery(= 2)   |  
|2         |  Dave        | Smith     | resultofquery (=1)   |
______________________________________________________________

___________________________________
|id    |memberid  |   date    | time  | group |
___________________________________
|1     |1         |2016-04-19 | 08:00 | 1     |
|2     |2         |2016-04-18 | 13:00 | 4     |
|3     |1         |2016-04-15 | 18:00 | 3     |
_______________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you include some sample input and output to put a face on the description?

Comment: No.  Include this in your question, formatted as tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your `members` table does not already have a column for the cancellations count, then add it:

```
ALTER TABLE members ADD numberofcancellations int AFTER lastname;
```

Now you can update `members` with the cancellation count:

```
UPDATE members t1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT memberid, COUNT(*) AS numberofcancellations
    FROM cancellations
    WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY memberid
) t2
   ON t1.memberid = t2.memberid
SET t1.numberofcancellations = COALESCE(t2.numberofcancellations, 0)
```

You will need to run this query once to initially populate the new column.  If you want to update a single member, then you can add a `WHERE` condition to the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE members t1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT memberid, COUNT(*) AS numberofcancellations
    FROM cancellations
    WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY memberid
) t2
   ON t1.memberid = t2.memberid
SET t1.numberofcancellations = COALESCE(t2.numberofcancellations, 0)
WHERE t1.memberid = 1   -- or whatever value you want
```

Comment: is there any way to have the the update query to run on the fly  (whenever the column is queried from other queries) or every x amount of time?

Comment: Yes, you could create a trigger to do this.  But I will not add further to my answer.  Please ask another question for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer provided, my question was that however.